# NodeJS - Error (response 408) when downloading a pdf with node-downloader-helper

Tags: node.js, timeout, node-modules

I want to download pdf with nodeJS, so I created a function with node-downloader-helper module (see below). This function is called multiples time to download a list of pdf.

```
function downloadPDF(url, dirname, index) {
    const options = {
        method: "GET", // Request Method Verb
        headers: {}, // Custom HTTP Header ex: Authorization, User-Agent
        fileName: `document${index}.pdf`, // Custom filename when saved
        forceResume: false, // If the server does not return the "accept-ranges" header, can be force if it does support it
        removeOnStop: true, // remove the file when is stopped (default:true)
        removeOnFail: true, // remove the file when fail (default:true)
        httpRequestOptions: {}, // Override the http request options
        httpsRequestOptions: {
            timeout: 10000, // Timeout in milliseconds
        }, // Override the https request options, ex: to add SSL Certs
        timeout: 10000, // Timeout in ms, 0 to disable (default:0)
    };

    const dl = new DownloaderHelper(encodeURI(url), dirname, options);

    dl.on('end', () => console.log('Download Completed'));
    dl.on('error', (err) => console.log('Download Failed', err));
    dl.start().catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

When I run my program I get this error : (and sometimes with server completely crash). I think it’s about a timeout error but I tried different methods but none worked.

```
Error: Response status was 408
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/CPE-Colle/node_modules/node-downloader-helper/dist/index.js:1:7055)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (node:_http_client:631:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:117:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:494:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10) {
  status: 408,
  body: ''
}
```

Comment: 408 does mean timeout, so you're correct on that one. Since this looks like a server-side problem, I think you should provide more details about the server - what is it, where, what's it doing, etc.?

Comment: did you get your ans? or should we help you, please mark your question as answered if you query is resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think found the solution, my puppeteer browser that was fetching pdf links wasn't closing so after a while my server crashed.